# What is this definition regarding the locker problem saying?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, recreational-mathematics

I am currently working on the famous "locker problem."  For those unfamiliar with this problem, [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2017047/the-locker-problem-why-squares) question here does a great job of explaining what it's all about.

My question today has to do entirely with the bottom of pg. 2 of [this](http://stanwagon.com/public/torrencewagon.pdf) document.  The author makes the following definition

> "Given a set $A$ of natural numbers, let
>   $e(A)$ be all natural numbers that are greater than or equal to an even number
>   (including $0$) of the elements of $A$."

to which he offers the following example

> "For example, if $A = \{3, 6, 9, . . .\}$, then $e(A) = \{1, 2, 6, 7, 8, 12, 13, 14, 18, 19, 20, . . .\} = \{n ∈ N : n ≡ 0, 1, 2 \mod 6\}$."

I do not understand what this function $e(A)$ is doing.  Perhaps the wording of his definition is awkward and is causing my confusion.  Do any of you know what he is saying here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$e(A)$ is the set of all positive integers $n$ such that the cardinality of the set $A\cap \{1,2,\dots,n\}$ is even.

Comment: So, to make sure I understand your point, if $A=\{3,6,9,\ldots\}$ as above then $1\in e(A)$ because $A\cap \{1\}$ has "even" cardinality of zero?

Comment: Yes. Why the quotation marks?

Comment: You know, I honestly can't give a good reason of why I put those there.  Let me edit those out.

Comment: Apparently, I can't edit that comment.